# Access RabbitMQ using floating IP associated with the VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, openstack, rabbitmq, network-security-group

I have a virtual machine (VM) running on OpenStack, on which I installed OpenStack using Packstack. I associated a floating IP with that VM.

In OpenStack, I configured the ingress access rules for all OpenStack components and RabbitMQ:

```
....

Ingress     IPv4    TCP     15672   0.0.0.0/0
Ingress     IPv4    TCP     5672    0.0.0.0/0
```

I can access both RabbitMQ and the management plugin from the VM. I even deployed a dummy consumer to the VM and it worked fine. However, I cannot access either of them from the floating IP. I can access the other OpenStack components successfully, such as Identity.

I tried modifying iptables, but it didn't work either:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 5671,5672,15672 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 5671,5672,15672 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Thank you for your help.

---

**Additional Information**

- After installing OpenStack on the VM I had to manually update the public endpoints to access the OpenStack services through the floating IP.
- I also updated (manually) the Horizon configuration file (/etc/httpd/conf.d/15-horizon_vhost.conf)

Form now onwards, localhost is 192.168.113.5, public IP is "floating IP".

**Telnet results**

(from the outside)

```
telnet <floating IP> 5672

Trying <floating IP>...
telnet: connect to address <floating IP>: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

(from the VM)

```
telnet localhost 5672
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

**Things I have tried**

lsof:

```
sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:5672 | grep LISTEN
<no-results>
```

ss:

```
sudo ss --tcp -f inet --listening --numeric --processes | grep 5672
LISTEN  0  128  *:25672  *:*  users:(("beam.smp",pid=1310,fd=44))
LISTEN  0  128  *:15672  *:*  users:(("beam.smp",pid=1310,fd=54))
```

netstat:

```
netstat --all --numeric --tcp --programs | grep 5672
tcp  0  0 0.0.0.0:25672  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  1310/beam.smp       
tcp  0  0 0.0.0.0:15672  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  1310/beam.smp
tcp  0  0 192.168.113.5:59962  192.168.113.5:5672  ESTABLISHED  3115/python2
...
tcp6  0  0  :::5672  :::*  LISTEN  1310/beam.smp       
tcp6  0  0  192.168.113.5:5672  192.168.113.5:59928  ESTABLISHED  1310/beam.smp
...
```

RabbitMQ:

```
rabbitmqctl list_connections
guest   192.168.113.5   59922   running
guest   192.168.113.5   59926   running
...
```

curl:

```
curl http://<floating IP>:15672/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <floating IP> port 15672: Network is unreachable
```

This is my RabbitMQ configuration file:

```
# /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config 

% This file managed by Puppet
% Template Path: rabbitmq/templates/rabbitmq.config
[
  {rabbit, [
    {tcp_listen_options, [
         {backlog,       128},
         {nodelay,       true},
         {linger,        {true, 0}},
         {exit_on_close, false}
    ]},
    {loopback_users, []},
    {tcp_listen_options, [binary,{packet, raw},{reuseaddr, true},{backlog, 128},{nodelay, true},{exit_on_close, false},{keepalive, true}]},
    {default_user, <<"guest">>},
    {default_pass, <<"guest">>}
  ]},
  {kernel, [

  ]}
].
% EOF
```

Comment: "I cannot access either of them from the floating IP" - you need to be specific about what you tried and report exactly what you saw. Did a connection time out or was it refused, that sort of thing. You should carefully read this guide and follow its troubleshooting directions: https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-networking.html

Comment: Thank you, @LukeBakken. I'll update the question and take a look at that article.

Comment: @LukeBakken, I updated my question

Comment: "Connection refused" and "network are unreachable" mean that there is something wrong with the networking in your OpenStack environment. This is not RabbitMQ-specific at this point.